# Can't connect to remote firebird server using ibase_connect()

Tags: php, firebird, interbase

I've been working with an Interbase connection on my localhost and are now trying to publish my application on a linux server (lets call it derp). But ibase_connect gives an error saying:

> Unable to complete network request to host "derp". Failed to establish
>   a connection.

On my localhost it works fine and I can ping derp from the server without any problem.

I don't have Firebird installed on the server but I figured it wouldn't be needed as I'm only connecting to a remote firebird host (on derp). Is it needed?

Comment: You usually need to install Firebird (or at least the client components) to be able to connect, however the error you show is generated by the Firebird (or interbase) client. Make sure that the Firebird server is running on derp and that port 3050 is accessible to external connections (ie: the server is registered on 0.0.0.0 or on a specific IP address, and port 3050 is not blocked by a firewall).

Comment: You should give us more informations, such as version number of firebird and what program or language / component you are using.  Maybe a dump of your code !!!!